# how to get data from excel to soapui request

Tags: groovy, soapui

I have already written a groovy script to read data from excel sheet, which is working fine.
Now i have two rows in excel. i want row1 to go to request1 and row2 to request2.

Below is my groovy script

```
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook
def fs = new FileInputStream(“C:\\Users\\singh532\\Desktop\\try1.xlsx”)
def wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fs)
def ws = wb.getSheet(“Sheet1”)
def r = ws.getPhysicalNumberOfRows()

for(def i=0; i<r; i++)
{
    def row = ws.getRow(i)
    def c = row.getPhysicalNumberOfCells()

    for (def j=0;j<c;j++)
    {
        def cell = row.getCell(j)
        def d = cell.getStringCellValue()
        log.info d
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using soapui 5.3

Comment: Would you please show the structure of your test case? such as how many steps (in the sequence with their types)? Are you trying data-driven tests?

Comment: I have one testcase with three test steps...Step 1. Above mentioned groovy script....step2 and step3 are two soap request.....Yes I am trying data-driven test.

Answer (score 1):

this is just to provide some ideas how it can be done

i'm using load test to run test steps multiple times (for multiple rows of data)

below is a structure of the test suite

**test steps**

- properties (COL1, COL2, COL3, COL...) corresponding to number of columns in my CSV file
- groovy script that loads data from CSV file and substitutes `COL*` property values with values from the CSV row that corresponds to current run iteration.

---

```
 public static class Const{
     public static ArrayList data=new ArrayList();
     static{
         //load data file statically
         new File('./my-data.csv').splitEachLine(","){
             data.add(it);
         }
     }
 }

 //get current run number and calculate row of data from it
 int row=context.getProperty( 'TotalRunCount');
 if(row==null)row=0;
 row=row%Const.data.size();
 //substitute properties with ones from file
 for(int i=0; i<Const.data[row].size(); i++){
     context.setProperty('COL'+(i+1), Const.data[row][i] );
 }
```

---

- the service call step that uses expressions with properties:

---

```
<a>
  <b>${=context.getProperty('COL1')}</b>
  <c>${=context.getProperty('COL2')}</c>
  ...
</a>
```

---

> Note: the number of rows in data file should correspond to limit of total runs in load test. if `total runs` will be larger than rows count in file then tests will be repeated.

[image]

Comment: That's neat.  I've also wondered how to squirt data into a load using SoapUI.  Thank you, I have something to play with now.